# How can I create persistent symlinks to my other drive?

Tags: linux, file-management, symbolic-link, kubuntu

When I create soft links within my /home folder to my other hdd (sdb) they no longer work when I restart my system. Do I have to mount my hdd to say /mnt/sdb on boot?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Softlinks are like a post-it note in a bookcase, stating "I am not the file you are looking for. Instead get it from this bookcase".   If you have two bookcase, place your post-it note in the first one and remove the second bookcase than that post-it note will not help you.

If you always want it to be available then you will have to make a copy.

Comment: So I edited /etc/fstab to mount /dev/sbd to /storage, then I was able to create symlinks to the files therein. On restart, the links worked :)